# How to use 'for' loop to split values and create list of dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x

Disclaimer: I am an absolute beginner in Python programming so please bear with me. I am taking a class for this and extremely desperate to get help.

I am creating a program that can read data from ANY text file which contains information like so:
**Produce, Is it a fruit (Y/N)**

```
String: "Apple","Y""Banana","Y""Pumpkin","N""Orange","Y""Eggplant","N"...
```

I need to convert the string to a list that will look like this:

```
"Apple","Y"
"Banana","Y"
"Pumpkin","N"
...
```

After that, I have to split/separate the values so they can fit into a dictionary that will look like this:

```
{"produce": xxx,"fruit": Yes/No}
```

For this task, I was told that I need to use the ***for*** loop to **split the lines** and create a **list of dictionaries**. But, I don't know how and where to put it.

Note that the program must be able to read data from any file. The user must also be able to modify whether the listed fruit/veg is indeed a fruit or not.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Are you sure your input string will look like this: `String: "Apple","Y""Banana","Y""Pumpkin","N""Orange","Y""Eggplant","N"...` not like this `String: "Apple","Y","Banana","Y","Pumpkin","N","Orange","Y","Eggplant","N"`

Comment: Hi! Yes, that's how it looks like from our exercise. No commas after Y/N.

Comment: so the expected result is `{"produce": "Orange","fruit": "Yes"}` or `{"orange" : "Yes", "Banana" : "Yes"}`

Comment: The first one: {"produce": "Orange","fruit": "Yes"}

Comment: but if this is the case `{"produce": "Orange","fruit": "Yes"}`  then every iteration will override the other value, Dictionary will not work like this!

Comment: I added a solution please have a look, and let me know If it worked for you or not

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want...

```
string="apple","Y","banana","Y","pumpkin","N"

dict={}
for i in range(0,len(string),2):
    dict[string[i]]=string[i+1]

for k,v in dict.items():
    print(k,v)
```

Answer (score 0):

So here I am after a lot of comments,
here is the suggested solution and this will work

```
x = "Apple","Y""Banana","Y""Pumpkin","N""Orange","Y""Eggplant","N"
length = len(x) 
mainList = []

def split_str(s):
  return [ch for ch in s]

for i in range(length):
    dict = {}
    if (i == 0):
        dict["produce"] = x[i]
        if(split_str(x[i+1])[0] == 'Y'):
            dict["fruit"] = 'Yes'
        else:
            dict["fruit"] = 'No'
        mainList.append(dict)
    else:
        if(i < 5):
            dict["produce"] = x[i][1:]
            if(split_str(x[i+1])[0] == 'Y'):
                dict["fruit"] = 'Yes'
            else:
                dict["fruit"] = 'No'
            mainList.append(dict)

print(mainList)
```

online fiddle link:
https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/b3de895b-8542-419d-841a-ad7ddf008d9a/?i=true

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your input. I posted my own answer. Since it was difficult for me to explain this stuff here, I had to get help outside the site as well. :( This is already done.

Comment: Is it working according to your requirements or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for those who answered my question. I was able to run this properly using the following codes:

```
# Read the contents from the file first.
def get_content(filename):
    f = open(filename,"r")
    if f.mode == 'r':
        content = f.read()
        content = content.replace('"','')
    return content

# Convert the contents to list of dictionaries (Y/N being a boolean).
def convert_to_list(content):
    string = sorted(content.split('\n'),key=str.lower)
    produce_list = []
    for x in string:
        a = x.split(',')
        b: bool = bool('Y' in a[1])
        d = dict({'produce': a[0], 'fruit':b})
        restaurant_list.append(d)
    return restaurant_list
```

I was able to complete this with help outside the site. Thank you so much for everyone's input!